# How to set the the variance of a stationary Gaussian AR(p) process given the variance of the innovation?

Tags: time-series, variance, covariance, stationarity, autoregressive

In [Cario and Nelson (1996)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6377(96)00017-X), we find the following.

Let {$Z_t$, t = 1, 2, ...} be a stationary Gaussian $AR(p)$ process.

$$Z_t = \alpha_1 Z_{t-1} + \alpha_2 Z_{t-2} + ... + \alpha_p Z_{t-p} + \epsilon_t$$

where {$\epsilon_t$} $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ is a series of independent random variables and $\sigma^2$ is selected so that the marginal distribution of the {$Z_t$} process is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Then, $\sigma^2 = 1 - \alpha_1 r_1 - \alpha_2 r_2 - \ ... \ -  \alpha_p r_p$

where $r_h = Corr(Z_t, Z_{t+h})$

---

*However*, I can't get to that result by myself. Here's my attempt.

$$Z_t (Z_t) = \Big(\alpha_1 Z_{t-1} + \alpha_2 Z_{t-2} + \ ... \ + \alpha_p Z_{t-p} + \epsilon_t \Big) (Z_t)$$

$$ \mathbb{E}[Z_t Z_t] = \mathbb{E}[\alpha_1 Z_{t-1} Z_t] + \mathbb{E}[\alpha_2 Z_{t-2} Z_t] + \ ... \ + \mathbb{E}[\alpha_p Z_{t-p} Z_t]  + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t Z_t] $$

$$\gamma(0) = \alpha_1 \mathbb{E}[Z_{t-1} Z_t] + \alpha_2 \mathbb{E}[Z_{t-2} Z_t] + \ ... \ + \alpha_p \mathbb{E}[Z_{t-p} Z_t] + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon Z_t]$$

$$\gamma(0) = \alpha_1 \gamma(1) + \alpha_2 \gamma(2) \ + ... + \ \alpha_p \gamma(p) + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon Z_t]$$

$$1 = \alpha_1 r(1) + \alpha_2 r(2) \ + ... + \ \alpha_p r(p) + \mathbb{E}[\epsilon Z_t]$$

where $\gamma(h) \doteq Cov(Z_t, Z_{t-h}$ and $r(h) = \frac{\gamma(h)}{\gamma(0)}$.

The expected value of two correlated random variables can be defined as $\mathbb{E}[X,Y] = Cov(X,Y) + \mu_x \mu_y$. Thus, $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t Z_t] = Cov(\epsilon_t,Z_t)$.

Therefore,

$$ Cov(\epsilon_t,Z_t) = 1 - \alpha_1 r(1) - \alpha_2 r(2) \ - ... - \ \alpha_p r(p)$$

**Here, I have two questions.**

1. How do I get the variance of $\epsilon$ from $Cov(\epsilon_t,Z_t)$? I think I made a mistake along the way.
2. Could I have reached the same result if I had started by applying the variance in all the terms? For instance, $var(Z_t) = var(\alpha_1 Z_{t-1}) + var(\alpha_2 Z_{t-2}) + ... + var(\alpha_p Z_{t-p}) + \sigma^2$? This way, I can easily get the $\sigma^2$ term, but all the $\alpha_i, i = 1, 2, ..., p$ should be squared, but in the paper they are not.

Comment: Use the independence of $\epsilon_t$ and $Z_t-\epsilon_t$ to compute $$E[\epsilon_t Z_t] = E[\epsilon_t(Z_t-\epsilon_t)] + E[\epsilon_t^2] =E[\epsilon_t]E[Z_t-\epsilon_t] + \sigma^2=\sigma^2.$$

Comment: Hello, @whuber, thank you so much for your comment. I saw what you did and it does work! But I'd like to know if it'd be possible for your to expound on your comment. Your trick (for a lack of a better word) wasn't obvious to me. In fact, I don't recall ever seeing it before, but it clearly works. Would you know of a book/reference in which I could find this "trick"? I'm not sure if there's anything special about or if it's "just arithmetic" of expectations?

Comment: It's no trick.  When comparing $\epsilon_t$ to $Z_t$ it should immediately be apparent that the only variables they have in common that might be correlated are $\epsilon_t$ itself, and then everything follows automatically.  Decomposing $Z_t$ as this sum is just one way (maybe one of the clearest ways) to point this out.  Otherwise, you would still get the right result by computing the covariance using the bilinearity property of covariance.